# Simple way to add all TextField delegates to a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Instead of manually adding each TextField delegate to the UIView, like this:

```
self.txtName.delegate = self;
self.txtAge.delegate = self;
```

Is there a quicker way of adding all TextField delegates to a UIView?

Alternatively, is there a way I can obtain the position of a TextField that has just received focus, without using UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: If they're all IBOutlets store them in an IBOutletCollection and iterate over it and set the delegates. Otherwise vikingosegundo's answer is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (UIView *aView in self.view.subviews) {

    if ([aView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {

        ((UITextField *)aView).delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile because `UIView` doesn't have a `delegate` property. You need to cast `aView`: `[(UITextField *)aView setDelegate:self];`.

Comment: (NSObject *aObject in self.view.subviews) would be better approach.

Comment: @mohacs: why would that be better?

Comment: @mohacs why would it? You'll only have UIViews in the array subviews.

Comment: I want to point out that this fails if the texfields are added to other subviews.

Comment: At the same time they are NSObject, instead of casting UIView to UITextField casting NSObject to UITextField make sense to me.

Comment: @mohacs, why does that makes more sense to you? there are only `UIViews`. if you want to cast them to the lowest level possible (for what reason ever?) go for `id`, as `id` accepts every message. NSObjects makes no sense at all.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Is there any downside? if there is and if you explain why then that would be great. I could say why I prefer NSObject just it looks more readable to me.

Comment: yeah, the infamous readable argument. `id` expresses: any object, and I can send any message. `UIView` expresses: any view object with all view and responser message being understand. `NSObject` expresses: @mohacs can read it more easily. But to send uiview messages I have to cast it — although there are only views.

Comment: Thank you for kind explanation, I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Create an outlet collection

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *textFields;
```

then loop over the textFields

```
for(UITextField *aTextField in self.textFields)
{
    aTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

There is a good post about IBOutlets on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/)

Comment: I prefer this way too.

Comment: Can't get this to work. The delegate assignments are never called (I've put them in viewDidLoad).

Answer (score 0):

> «Two or more: Use a for» — Edsger W. Dijkstra

```
[@[self.txtNames, self.txtAge] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField *tf, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    tf.delegate = self;
}];
```

<sub>Ok: not a for. But the same principle.</sub>

---

If you want to use a `for`, you could use Fast Enumeration instead of block-based Enumeration.

```
for (UITextField *tf in @[self.txtNames, self.txtAge]) {
    tf.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add ***UITextFieldDelegate*** at the end of your view controller header file.

```
@interface AddressesViewController : ViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```